# Remotely access a qsub compute node

Tags: remote-access, rpc, mbeans, qsub

Using `qsub`, I have submitted a long running job that spawns two Java processes; one of which is listening for Java RMI calls on some port. Say qsub assigns that job to node "compute-0-37". **How can I communicate with compute-0-37 remotely (on a node other than the head node) over an RPC call (Java RMI in this case)?**

I have not been able to find this from reading existing docs (e.g. http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html, http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm). As far as I can tell, the only way to access a compute node directly is from the head node, but it seems like that would be pretty restrictive for use cases like mine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't find any documentation in the resource management software documentation is because this isn't a resource management software question. Accessing worker nodes is simply that: a function of network access. Whether you're hoping to do RPC communication between the nodes themselves, or with some machine on a different subnet, you should be able to do so (provided that site policies and the system administator/s allow it).

Comment: To clarify: for example, for communication between nodes, this may simply be a matter of disabling iptables, at least to confirm that the firewall isn't blocking on the nodes.